# Boto3/AWS: "ImageId doesn't exist" when creating Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ami

I've made a copy of an AMI and I'm trying to run it with this code:

```
import boto3

instance_id=("i-0e2bbdf4fc43bf6db")

client = boto3.client("ec2",region_name="us-west-2")
ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2")

ec2.create_instances(ImageId="ami-9d623ee5",MinCount=1,MaxCount=1)
```

A ClientError is returned:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAMIID.NotFound) when calling the RunInstances operation: The image id '[ami-9d623ee5]' does not exist
```

What could the issue be?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you see that AMI ID on your AWS console (or, if you don't have access, do you see it by calling DescribeImages (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html))? Is it in the same region as you are passing (us-west-2) ?

Comment: What do you mean `make a copy of an AMI` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the AMI is in the same region ...

Your code is wrong: Change to be similar to the following:

```
import boto3

instance_id=("i-0e2bbdf4fc43bf6db")

session = boto3.Session("ec2",region_name="us-west-2")
ec2 = session.resource("ec2")

OR

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

ec2.create_instances(ImageId="ami-9d623ee5",MinCount=1,MaxCount=1)
```